# Python Module not found when installed with python -m pip install -e <my_package>

Tags: python, installation, pip

I am attempting to install a local directory as a python package, so as to make other modules in the package accessible to each other, similarly to how java files are able to access each other.

python -m pip list | grep sumobot returns:
`sumobot                          0.1         /home/pi/Documents/sumobot`

However, trying to run a file in the package returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/test_motor.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sumobot.robot_hardware.motor import RawMotor as Motor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sumobot'
```

I'd like to understand how this can be the case, as from my reading, installing with python -m pip should fix issues of wrong python versions. Also, if there is a better way to do what I am looking to do, please let me know.
If it makes a difference, I am running this on a raspberry pi zero, and the contents of my setup.py (which was placed in the same directory as my sumobot package) are as follows:

````
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='sumobot',
      version='0.1',
      description='is a sumobot!',
      packages=['sumobot'])```
````

Comment: What does `pip list -v` return?

Comment: pip list -v returns the same thing exactly